# changing the placeholder text on a site template

Tags: jquery, yui, squarespace

I'm using a Squarespace template and trying to change the search placeholder text (Type to search...).

I tried searching their forums and nothing has helped.  I figure some simple jquery could do the trick, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
<form id="yui_3_17_2_2_1421895144095_1398" _lpchecked="1">
    <input placeholder="Type to search..." type="text" 
           spellcheck="false" value="" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1421895144095_1397">
</form>
```

Comment: Didn't changing the placeholder attribute work?

Comment: @TiagoGoddard my jquery skills are week.  I tried:

`$("#yui_3_17_2_2_1421895144095_1398").attr("placeholder", "Recherche");`

Comment: thats the forms id. its wrong. try `$("#yui_3_17_2_2_1421895144095_1397").attr("placeholder", "Recherche");`

Comment: @naveen I've tried both, neither work.

Comment: where did you write the js code?

Comment: @naveen in the header code injection.  I just realized the Squarespace dedicated search page is a strange one.  Every time you refresh the page the id changes for the input.  When I use the console in Chrome I type in the code, it works, when I refresh it's broken and the id is different.

Comment: how many form does the page have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("form").find("input").attr("placeholder", "Recherche");
```

Or place this just above the `body` close tag

```
$(function () {
    $("form").each(function () {
        var inputElm = $(this).find("input");
        var ph = inputElm.attr("placeholder")
        if (ph && ph === "Type to search...") {
            inputElm.attr("placeholder", "Recherche");
        }
    });
});
```

If you want YUI (natively supported by squarespace), try this.

```
Y.one('form').one('input').setAttribute('placeholder', 'Recherche');
```

Or

```
Y.all('form').each(function (node) {
    var inputElm = node.one('input');
    var ph = inputElm.getAttribute('placeholder');
    if (ph && ph === "Type to search...") {
        inputElm.setAttribute("placeholder", "Recherche");
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually just tried that 5 min ago....didn't work unfortunately.  Really appreciate your help!
It works in Chrome console, but not when put into the site header code.

Comment: That worked!!!  It doesn't work when I'm logged in to the site, but when I'm logged out it works.  Thank you!!!  If only I understood the code haha.  I get lost at the the "if (ph && ph === " section. :-(.  I've only learned some basic jquery.